# I've got a Syntax Error while doing SQL

Tags: sql

I've got a Syntax Error while doing SQL

```
SELECT 
    Title AS 'Title of Item', 
    PubYear AS 'Year of Publication', 
    Round(ReplacementCost/1.1 AS 'ReplacementCost(Actual)', 1), 
    Round(LostFee/1.1 AS 'LostFee(Actual)', 1)

FROM Item

WHERE PubYear IN (2001, 2002)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the syntax error in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the `ROUND()` function in MySQL is:

```
ROUND( number, [ decimal_places ] )
```

You were apparently trying to embed the alias inside the call to `ROUND()`, which doesn't make sense.

Corrected version:

```
SELECT 
    Title AS 'Title of Item', 
    PubYear AS 'Year of Publication', 
    Round(ReplacementCost/1.1, 1) AS 'ReplacementCost(Actual)', 
    Round(LostFee/1.1, 1) AS 'LostFee(Actual)'
FROM Item
WHERE PubYear IN (2001, 2002)
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT
Title AS 'Title of Item',
PubYear AS 'Year of Publication', 
Round(ReplacementCost/1.1, 1)  AS 'ReplacementCost(Actual)', 
Round(LostFee/1.1 , 1) AS 'LostFee(Actual)'

FROM Item

WHERE PubYear IN (2001, 2002)
```

I don't know if that fixes your problem but since I can not comment yet I am posting this to help.